# How to get just GET and POST params as hash in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I would like to get any additional `GET` and `POST` **params** in Rails without Rails' own additions such as `controller`, `format`, etc...

`params.inspect` gave me what I want but it has some keys that Rails adds for me such as `controller` or `format`. I only want to get user input `GET` and `POST` params as hash. How can I do that? I cannot find anything.

**URL:**

`http:/test.com/some/path?query1=1&query2=1`

**Run:**

`puts params.inspect`

**Expected:**

`{"query1"=>"1", "query2"=>"1"}`

**Actual:**

`{"query1"=>"1", "query2"=>"1", "format"=>":json", "controller"=>"get", "action"=>"index", "folder"=>"some/path"}`

Also this can be combined with POST request. I only want to filter them and only get them as hash.

I execute this from inside of a controller. Rails 5 used.

Comment: Where are you executing this from? What version of rails are you using.

Comment: @engineersmnky, I execute this from inside of a controller. Rails 5 used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> You should have permitted params ([Strong parameters](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html)).

In your controller have permitted params method.

```
def your_params
  params.permit(:query1, :query2)
end
```

If you wish to have a hash of those you can do

```
your_params.to_h #This will return hash of permitted params
```

*Update:*

Incase you have multiple `query*` type of parameters you can [select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-select) them and [permit!](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit-21). Here is a command line explanation

```
# passing the list of parameters
> params = ActionController::Parameters.new({query1: 'aa', query2: 'bb', query3: 'cc', controller: 'users', action: 'index'})
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"query1"=>"aa", "query2"=>"bb", "query3"=>"cc", "controller"=>"users", "action"=>"index"} permitted: false>

# Select all the parameters of type query<integer>
> all_queries = params.select {|i| i.match?(/query\d/) }
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"query1"=>"aa", "query2"=>"bb", "query3"=>"cc"} permitted: false>

 # mark the selected as permitted
> all_queries.permit!
=> <ActionController::Parameters {"query1"=>"aa", "query2"=>"bb", "query3"=>"cc"} permitted: true>

# get them as hash
> all_queries.to_h
=> {"query1"=>"aa", "query2"=>"bb", "query3"=>"cc"}
```

Controller method will look like

```
# getting all query<integer> like params
def your_params
  params.select {|param| param.match?(/query\d/}.permit!
end
```

Comment: query1 and query2 is not static. It may contains much much more parameters. Have no strict/permitted keys for query. But, this will be helpful for me for other issue. See, I am trying to collect and calculate all provided query parameters regardless permitted or not permitted.

Comment: are they namespaced in any other params. Eg: users: [:query1, query2] ?

Comment: I am trying to collect all user provided query (GET and POST) parameters and hash them. That's why I cannot permit any. This has nothing to do with database or any action like critical.

Comment: Actually, permit may work better in my situation. About security. So I can filter all unnecessary queries and only grab what I need.

Comment: I have updated my answer on how to still whitelist `query*` parameter and thn get the whitelisted as hash

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you for your time and explaining to me.

Answer (score 1):

In the controller, you have access to a `request` object. `request` has a method `query_parameters`, which will return a hash of just the explicitly supplied parameters.

```
`request.query_parameters`
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-query_parameters

Comment: Is this also includes user provided POST parameters? Oh, the same page shows for `request_parameters()`. So I will compare and combine them.